# Can we define width of a box in CSS dynamically?

Tags: python, html, css, django-views

In django project, in views.py file we provide some data in context, and then we access it in html file using jinja templating {{...}}. But I need to use that data as pixel size for width of a box.

I am new to stackoverflow as well, so I don't know how to post views.py code. So I am writing it here.

##This is my views.py code##

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):

    px_size = 400

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'px_size':px_size})
```

##views.py code ends here##

And here is my index.html code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        p{
            background-color: rgb(140, 132, 166);
            width: 400px;
            font-size: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>I need to set this box's width as {{px_size}} px, dynamically</p>
    Here in body of html we can take px size from views as context. 
    <br>
    But I want to use this px_size to be the px size of width in css.
    <br>
    I have mentioned statically in style tag width as 400px.
    <br>
    How can I take it dynamically from the context?
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<p style="width:{{px_size}}px"></p>
```

Comment: Does't work.....

Comment: it needs the closing tag ofc, don't just steal the answer and add the closing tag if you really thought it needed to be added you could have just edited the question, but I guess you want some points

Comment: It's not about points... I'm trying to help... The suggested edit queue is full... I have enough points

Comment: I'm sorry for the rude comment, I'm going to update the code

Comment: That's better... See I deleted my answer

Comment: Guys please don't fight. I understood what @IvanAmbla was suggesting, and I got my solution. Still there is some problem. I am using VS code for editing, and there it shows 3 problems

proprerty value expected css(css-proprerty value expected)

Comment: vs code is analyzing the template file expecting to get a correct css syntax, this is not the case ofc because you can't write something like that in normal html css, the correct syntax comes out only after the template have been filled, you either need a plug-in/setting that recognise template files (e.g. understands {{…}}) or turn off syntax checking for template files.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `aspect-ratio` property. This dynamically scales based of a ratio from a given value.

So for example, if you want to use a 1/1 ratio, and assuming `px_size` is defined, try

```
        p{
            background-color: rgb(140, 132, 166);
            aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
            width: {{px_size}};
            font-size: 30px;
        }
```